# Dynamically change color of rows in a SwiftUI List

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list

In a SwiftUI app I want to do the following and I am wondering how to tackle the problem. I hope someone can give me a hint.

I have a list with about seven or eight rows and below the list is a button. When I tap the button the app plays audio files (one for each row). This is already working.

And here is what I want to implement:
When I tap the button, I want each row to change color one after the other while the matching audio file is playing.

The sound files are handled by a class like the one below with an audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying method to detect when a file play has ended.

```
class AudioEngine: NSObject,ObservableObject,AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
    @Published var isPlaying:Bool = false {
        willSet {
            if newValue == true {
                playAudio()
            }
        }
    }
    ....
    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer,   successfully flag: Bool) {
        ....
    }
}
```

An instance of AudioEngine is created with:

```
let soundManager = AudioEngine()
........
```

And this shows the view with the list and the button:

```
VStack {
    // Display the list of items:
    ListItemsView(sentenceList: sntncLst, moc: moc)
    // Display the button to play all the items:
    Button(action: {
        if !soundManager.isPlaying {self.playAllAudio(sntncLst)}
        else {soundManager.stopAudio()}
    })
    {
        Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "speaker.png")!)
            .padding(.bottom, 17)
    }
}
....

func playAllAudio(_ sndList:[AudioList]) {
    for sentence in sndList {
        soundManager.filesArray.append(sentence.soundFile!)
    }
    soundManager.serialPlayAudio()
}
```

Comment: In SwiftUI you need to get your model right.  Can you show your model for your view?  For example, say it has an array of items; Those items should be structs or objects with details of the audio file (name, etc) and an `isPlaying` boolean. Now, as long as your `isPlaying` boolean is true/false according to the playing state your SwiftUI view just checks it and renders the appropriate colour.  The trick is updating your model in the `didFinishPlaying` delegate method

Comment: I added some more relevant code inside the post.
I have an isPlaying flag inside the AudioEngine class.
But not for each row in the list.

If one looks inside the playAllAudio function one can see that soundManager.serialPlayAudio() takes care of playing all the audio files. There should be a way for soundManager to let the list view know that a given audio file has started or finished playing.

Comment: Your view shouldn't know anything about your sound manager.  Your view model should have the list of sounds and the sound manager reference.  Your view asks the view model to play a sound; the view model asks the sound manager.  You need a way for your sound manager to let the view model know when a sound has finished or a new sound starts playing - I suggest that the view model supplies closures to the sound manager to do this.  Your view model then updates the `nowPlaying` @Published property.  The view then needs to generate the list and compare each list item against `nowPlaying`

Comment: You write "the view model supplies closures to the sound manager". How exactly do you do that? Do you have any example?

Comment: In your sound manager you would declare a property something `var soundDidEndHandler: ((AudioList)->Void)?` and then in your model you assign a closure to this property. In the `didFinishPlaying` delegate method you can invoke the closure `self.soundDidEndHandler?(currentAudio)`

Comment: I see. Thanks, I will try that.